# How to append two string or number for the function name in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
for(i=0;i< 6; i++ ){
    function myFunc + 1() {
        alert(i);
    }
}

myFunc1();
```

This is my code I want to create function from `myFunc1` to `myFunc6`, but it seems like it does not work, why??

Comment: This is *very* poor code, but if you really have to, check out eval()

Comment: Why dont you create different cases inside one function?

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? Perhaps StackOverflow can suggest a way to refactor your code.

Comment: i am trying to create myFunc1 to myFunc6 function as the question specified

Comment: That really doesn't answer my question. Why do you think you need to create these functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    window['myFunc' + i] = (function(i) {
        alert(i);
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Do this. Sean's right. Hopefully Sean explains the classic closure problem you've run into (and which Sean fixes by creating a new closure for each iteration of i)

Comment: what the meaning of window[]??any reference or documentation on this??so I can know more

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this :

```
var myFuncs = [];

for ( i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
   (function(i){ myFuncs.push(function() { alert(i) }); })(i);
}

myFuncs[0]();
```